# C++ Template for pointer to member function of undetermined class, with different arguments, called as argument

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I am not an advanced programmer. The short version of the problem would be: how can I make a template for a global function that calls a pointer to a member function of classes that are only known at runtime (and who have different kind of arguments)?

The function is global and its declaration is this:

```
template<class T>
const double gExtFunc(const double &x,  \
                      const double &y,  \
                      const double &ep, \
                      const double &es, \
                      // function pointer here
                      const double &a,     \
                      const double &k,  \
                      double &mid_OUT,  \
                      short  &i_OUT,    \
                      double &eps_OUT,  \
                      short  &trip_OUT);
```

This gets called inside some (`virtual public`) classes. For example (not using `ellipsis`):

```
class DerivedA: virtual public Base
{
public:
    void funcA(...)
    {
        // ...
        m_varA = gExtFunc(...);
        // ... 
    }
    // ...
    const double commonFunc(const double &a, const double &k) const;
};

const double DerivedA::commonFunc(const double &a, const double &k) const
{
    // ...
}
```

The `Base` class is just for common variables, mostly. The pointer to function points to `commonFunc()` which has the same name in all virtual classes, but different definitions and type of arguments in each. For example, the above `DerivedA` uses it with two `const double&` arguments, while a `DerivedE` with:

```
const double DerivedE::commonFunc(const int &n, const double &k) const;
```

Now, I managed to make it work with a lambda function (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053877/c-external-function-with-pointer-to-function-as-parameter-used-inside-a-class), when I only had one `m_varA`), which meant the function pointer argument of `gExtFunc()` was this:

```
const double gExtFunc(..., std::function<const double(const double&, const double&)> fPnt, ...)
```

and it was called, for ex. inside `DerivedA`, as:

```
m_varA = gExtFunc(..., [this](const double &a, const double &k){ return commonFunc(a, k); }, ...)
```

and it worked, but only as long as it was called inside one class, only. As soon as I tried calling it in `DerivedE`, for `m_varE`, it, too, failed: `was not declared in this scope`, pointing to its definition of `m_varE`.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110895/c-pointer-to-member-function-of-an-unknown-class) answer, but that requires me to first create an object, which I can't do. So I tried to go around it and replace the pointer to function argument like this:

```
template<class T>  // first the template, above the function
const double gExtFunc(..., T *t, const double(T::*t)(const double&, const double&) fPnt, ...)
```

and, inside the definition: `t->fPnt(...)`. But how would `gExtFunc()` be called? I tried this:

```
m_varA = gExtFunc(..., new DerivedA(), &DerivedA::commonFunc, ...)
```

but it fails, `was not declared in this scope`, same as above. I am stuck here. If there is an alternative to what I am trying to do, I'm very much willing to change it.

---

EDIT:

As a temporary, ugly solution, I copied the `gExtFunc()` to each class that needs it, trimmed & adjusted, including giving up pointer to function, just a direct call of the member function `commonFunc()`. There are only 3 cases, for now, but the future may bring more, which is why I consider this to be ugly and why the question is still valid.

Comment: Are 10 function parameters really the best way implement this?

Comment: @StoryTeller I have to include all cases, the 1st two of them are necessary, the next four are for `fPnt()` inside, depending on which `commonFunc()` is called from which class, then the last 4 are for debugging, only. I could give them up, but they do provide valuable information as the whole `gExtFunc()` has some iterations inside that adjust themselves, dynamically, based on `x` and `y`. So, currently, 10 it is... :-)

Answer (score 1):

This solution would do it (AClass is a test class):

```
class AClass
{
    private:
        std::string s_;
        unsigned short a_;

    public:
        AClass(const std::string& __s, unsigned short __a) : s_(__s), a_(__a) {}

        void m_Test(unsigned short __a, const std::string& __s) 
        {
            a_ += __a;
            s_.append(__s);
        }

        unsigned short getA() { return a_; }
        std::string getS() { return s_; }
};

template <typename T, typename R, typename ...Args>
R proxycall(T & obj, R (T::*mf)(Args...), Args &&... args)
{
    return (obj.*mf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename T, T> struct proxy;

template <typename T, typename R, typename ...Args, R(T::*mf)(Args...)>
struct proxy<R(T::*)(Args...), mf>
{
    static R call(T & obj, Args &&... args)
    {
        return (obj.*mf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

int main()
{
    AClass a("I ", 2);
    proxy<void(AClass::*)(unsigned short, const std::string&), &AClass::m_Test>::call(a, 23 , "am: ");

    std::cout << a.getS() << a.getA() << "\n";

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I don't remember who wrote this, but it is someone from the forum. Thanks to him.

### Edit

You could also use polymorphism mechanisms if you can make your commonFunc virtual. I don't know if this will suits your needs, but here is a sample:

```
class AClass;

double gExtFunc(AClass* __acl, const double& __a, const double& __b, const double& __f);

class AClass
{
    private:
        const std::string& aClass = "AClass";

    protected:
        double r_;

    public:
        AClass() : r_(0) {}

        void func_A()
        {
            r_ = gExtFunc(this, 2.0, 1.5, 300.011);
        }

        virtual double m_Test(const double& __a, const double& __b) 
        {
            return __a * __b;
        }

        double getR() { return r_; }
        void setR(const double& __r) { r_ = __r; }

        virtual const std::string& getClass() { return aClass; }
};

class BClass : virtual public AClass
{
    private:
        const std::string& bClass = "BClass";

    public:
        BClass() : AClass() {}

        void func_A()
        {
            r_ = gExtFunc(this, 3.0, 1.5, 311.128);
        }

        virtual double m_Test(const double& __a, const double& __b)
        {
            return __a * __b;
        }

        const std::string& getClass() { return bClass; }
};

double gExtFunc(AClass* __acl, const double& __a, const double& __b, const double& __f)
{
    double d = __acl->m_Test(__a, __b);
    return d * __f;
}

int main()
{
    AClass a;
    BClass b;

    a.func_A();
    b.func_A();

    std::cout << a.getR() << "\n" << a.getClass() << "\n\n";
    std::cout << b.getR() << "\n" << b.getClass() << "\n";

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This goes a bit over my head, but what I see is that I create a function based on a struct that holds templates for `commonFunc()`'s arguments, such that when I create an `AClass` object, it will be able to call whichever function from whichever class, based on arguments. Do I come anywhere close? If yes, this implies I have to make an object, which I can't. Nothing in what I'm doing takes place inside `main()`. `gExtFunc()` is global, `DerivedA`&co are classes, all `commonFunc()` are member functions of these, and `m_varA`&co are also member variables of these classes. To top it all, (cont)

Comment: ...`gExtFunc()` needs to call `commonFunc()` for each `m_varA`, m_varE`, etc, because it depends on it. If it matters, `gExtFunc()` is some root finding algorithm, while all member functions `commonFunc()` are polynomial functions of varying complexity. Some are as simple as trigonometric functions, others involve more complex functions. Thank you for the answer, though, I'll try to see maybe I can adapt it? But first I have to understand it.

Comment: "it will be able to call whichever function from whichever class, based on arguments" That's it.

Comment: But will I be able to do it without creating an `AClass` object? Or, how could I mix the above to fit inside one of `gExtFunc()`'s arguments? Actually, I think I got it: instead of a pointer to function as argument I use `AClass &aclass`, then use it inside `gExtFunc()` as `class->commonFunc()`, instead of `fPnt()`. This might work, I'm on it now.

Comment: Can you make your commonFunc virtual ?

Comment: I could, all classes that have `commonFunc()` are `virtual public` because there's a diamond sort in there, with many facets. Something like `Base > DerivedA > LastClass`, `Base > DerivedB > LastClass`, etc. What would that accomplish? But there's another problem now: `gExtFunc` needs to call `commonFunc()` inside in different ways for the root finding algorithm. I think my whole problem got very ugly now.

Comment: That's not a bad solution, but, as I mentioned, I don't get to be in `main()`. `m_varA`&co belong to `DerivedA`&co, they're initialized within a member function (say `fncA()`&co), which gets called by the constructor from `LastClass`. Still, my last problem remains: the pointer inside `gExtFunc()` needs to be called as either `fPnt(x,y)-es*ep` for `DerivedA`, or as `fPnt(x,y)/fPnt(x,y/k)-ep/es` for `DerivedE`, etc, which means I have to make some other global function with a `switch/case`... It's ugly, but mostly I'm sorry I can't give more details for such a complicated program.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to downvote my answer if it is wrong. I am just trying to help.
I don't have the mental capacity to read all of that and understand your exact question, but I think I understand the basis of your problem. I am assuming you are doing something like making a function where an argument can vary like:

```
template <typename T> func(T arg1){}
```

and somewhere else in code you are expecting that `T` to be an `int` or a `char *` or whatever but you are having trouble converting `T` to the proper type.

What I would do is work in memory. My function would be something like

```
enum types {
    OBJECT,
    INT,
    STRING
};

int type;
int addrOfType;

void func(int addr, int typ) {
    type = typ;
    addrOfType = typ;
}
```

and to call it do something like

```
object argument;
func((int)&argument,OBJECT);
```

and somewhere else in the code you are retrieving the data

```
switch (type) {
    case OBJECT:
        object obj = *(object*)addrOfType;
        //do whatever with obj
        break;
}
```

I hope that helped. It looked like a tough question so I figured I would attempt to try and help as I sit here bored. Feel free to neg my answer if it is terrible. It is so hard to post on mobile.

Comment: I don't think this would work, thanks for the answer, though. In short, what I have is a member variable, `m_varA`, or `m_varE`, depending on class, calling an external, global function, `gExtFunc()`, who takes a pointer to member function as argument. This member function is `commonFunc()`, it has the same name in all classes that have it, but its definition and argument types differ from class to class. `DerivedA` might use it with `(double,double)`, `DerivedE` with `(int,double)`. I can get over this by making all use `(double,double)` and pass an `int` instead, where needed, but in rest...

Comment: I think if you specify the arguments as (unsigned int) and use &argument you can parse it as the type of variable you want it to be like this:
`void commonFunc(unsigned int arg1, unsigned int arg2) {
double a = *(double*)arg1;
int b = *(int*)arg2;
}

double q = 23458;
int r = 3426;
commonFunc(&q,&r);`